Pulling Product Data from Amazon with Curl
I want to get data from product links and product details from Amazon search result. For example: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=beauty& this is an Amazon product listing link. I want to pull product links from here and bring the data of those products. Please can someone help?
In addition, I want to make it automatically pass the page, but I need to solve this problem first, that's all I can do.
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip',
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=dbeauty',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
));
$html = curl_exec($ch);

if($html === false) {
    die("CURL error: " . curl_error($ch));
}

$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$domd->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($domd);
$links = $xpath->query('//a[contains(@class, "a-link-normal")]/@href');
$links_to_scrape = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 10 && $i < $links->length; $i++) {
    $url = $links[$i]->nodeValue;
    if (strpos($url, 'https://') !== 0) {
        $url = 'https://www.amazon.com' . $url;
    }
    $links_to_scrape[] = $url;
}
foreach ($links_to_scrape as $link) {
    echo $link . "\n";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip',
        CURLOPT_URL => $link,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    ));
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    if($html === false) {
        echo "CURL error: " . curl_error($ch);
        continue;
    }

    $domd = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $domd->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $xp = new DOMXPath($domd);

    $productName = $xp->query('//span[@id="productTitle"]');
    $stock = $xp->query('//div[@id="availability"]');
    $price = $xp->query('//span[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]');
    $image = $xp->query('//img[@id="landingImage"]/@src');
    $category = $xp->query('//a[@class="a-link-normal a-color-tertiary"]');
    $productDescription = $xp->query('//div[@id="aplus"]');

    if ($productName->length > 0) {
        echo "Ürün adı: " . $productName->item(0)->nodeValue . "\n";
    }
    if ($stock->length > 0) {
        echo "Stok durumu: " . trim($stock->item(0)->textContent) . "\n";
    }
    if ($price->length > 0) {
        echo "Fiyat: " . trim($price->item(0)->textContent) . "\n";
    }
    if ($image->length > 0) {
        echo "Ürün resmi: " . $image->item(0)->nodeValue . "\n";
    }
    if ($category->length > 0) {
        echo "Kategori: " . $category->item(0)->nodeValue . "\n";
    }
    if ($productDescription->length > 0) {
        echo "Ürün açıklaması: " . $productDescription->item(0)->nodeValue . "\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
?>



Use an API. Don't scrape HTML.

@Olivier I couldn't find a free api so I tried this

When you run your code, what is the output? What do you get from scraping the amazon page? Are the products in the scrape? They might aswell be loaded later using JavaScript
